# PYTHON - My list adder function don't want to pass to another function

Tags: python, list, function, loops, args

I'm a beginner in Python and I'm trying to create different simple code to train and learn a lot.

But here I stuck on the fact that I can't pass one function args to an another one !

Here is my code :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests 

global proxy
global port
validsocklist = []
validportlist = []

print('Veuillez entrer la source de votre liste.txt de proxy: ')
list = raw_input()
f = open(list, 'r')


proxylist = open(list).read().splitlines()
proxycut = [x.split(':', 1)[0] for x in proxylist]
portcut = [x.split(':', 1)[1] for x in proxylist]


numberofline = 0
for line in f:
    numberofline += 1
print('Nombre de proxys: {}'.format(numberofline))


def list():
    global proxy
    global port
    pro = -1
    for x in proxycut:
        pro += 1
        proxy = proxycut[pro]
        port = portcut[pro]
        print(proxy)
        print(port)
        test()
    print('Les proxys socks validés par google sont :')
    valid = -1
    for x in validsocklist:
        valid += 1
        print('{}:{}'.format(validsocklist[valid],validportlist[valid]))

def test():
    global proxy
    global port 
    proxies = {
                  'http': 'socks5://{}:{}'.format(proxy,port),
                  'https': 'socks5://{}:{}'.format(proxy,port)
    }
    try:
        r = requests.get('http://www.google.com', timeout=10, proxies=proxies)
        print(r.status_code)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            adder()
    except:
        pass    

def adder():
    validsocklist.append(proxycut[pro])
    validportlist.append(portcut[pro])    

list()
```

Please explain me, I don't want a better code or a final code, I want to UNDERSTAND !

The result is that it don't print the good proxys at the end :

Thank you all a lot !

Comment: I'm finding it quite unclear what you're trying to do. You aren't passing arguments to any of your functions. Your functions don't have any parameters.

Comment: Hmm...`def list():` use some other name there. `list` is already reserved as built-in. And here as well: `list = raw_input()`.

Comment: The final result is that it's not showing properly the good proxy passed to validproxylist and validsocklist ! Thank you

Comment: Oh I don't see that thank you a lot Austin !

Comment: Take that exercise: [Python - Functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm)

Comment: Please I still don't understand why my adder() func is not append properly the proxy and the port to the list ! I do this to make the test() func threaded to make it really fast ! Thanks !